# Referencing a Dynamic Workbook Name - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a workbook ("Control Panel.xlsm") for a work college to use as a storing place for all our macros we use in our day to day tasks. She is not VBA literate.
One of the macros, (see code below) organizes another workbook so that it add a descriptive column at the end of a table.

```
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim wbNames As Variant, wb As Workbook, w As Workbook, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
    wbNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July, August, September, October,November,December")
    For Each w In Workbooks
        For Each El In wbNames
            If w.Name = "Docs_Tracker_" & El & " 2020.xlsm" Then
                Set wb = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next
      Next
    
    '1. Column AB - Descriptive Field - Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable
If wb Is Nothing Then Stop
    Set tbl = wb.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
    With tbl
            .ListColumns.Add.Name = "Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable"
    End With
        wb.Activate
        Range("AB2:AB" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-22],"" - "",RC[-26],"" - "",RC[-15])"
```

What I would like to do is reference the workbook **("Docs_Tracker_April 2020.xlsm")** so that the code still works even as the workbook reference name changes (Docs_Tracker_May 2020, Docs_Tracker_June 2020 etc)

I have tried the ActiveWorkbook, workbook Indexing method however they can have bugging issues, and isn't as foolproof with someone who isn't as familiar as VBA as my work college is.

If someone could teach me this I will apply it to all my macros they all have a similar issue. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a rule of the workbook naming? Do you want the procedure working for any workbook name containing, "January", "February" etc. instead of "April"? What about two such workbooks will be open in the same time?

Comment: So no, only two workbooks will be open ("control panel.xlsm" and "Docs tracker depending on the month" - I will give the code you have given me below a try and get back to you

Comment: Not sure, what the problem is? Do you want to store macros in one workbook (and change it name every month) or in several workbooks depending on month name? Do you wnat to update links or what?

Comment: The code should work well, I think. If you need me to integrate it in your sub, this will not be a problem, but I think it is easy to do that by yourself... You only have to replace `Set wb = Workbooks("Docs_Tracker_April 2020.xlsm")` with the code I supplied, but please properly declare the necessary variables.

Comment: apologies @FaneDuru I forgot to tag. I have amended code above at your suggestions. My code is now bugging at the line Set tbl = wb.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table_owssvr"). any help on why?

Comment: @MaciejLos. I am designing a workbook with all the macros we use in our job. one of those jobs is to organize a data sheet of information (Docs Tracker) which changes month to month. what I would like to do is to have a macro that runs the same job even as the data sheet changes. (doc tracker April, Doc tracker may etc)

Comment: This means that any open workbook does not match the definition algorithm... Try putting the line `If wb is Nothing then Stop`, just above the line raising the error. Can you post here the workbook name you try using when the error is returned? Maybe the name has wrongly built. Without the space before 2020, or with underscore, something not matching the example you posted...

Comment: @FaneDuru i am still getting the same issue unfortunately. I have amended the code above to reflect your recommended changes. the name is Docs_Tracker_April 2020.xlsm

Comment: And If you did what I suggested, does the code stop on the new inserted code line?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes sir that is correct. have I correctly labelled the months of the split function? I am attempting to edit that line

Comment: This means that my assumption is correct. Did you use the array as my code builds it, or used spaces after each comma?

Comment: @FaneDuru perfect. thank you. we got there in the end!

Comment: But, what was the problem, in fact?

Comment: my mistake. i didnt amend the Split function appropriately and add the (,",") at the end of the function. thank you

Comment: Ok. Good for you! I am glad that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please. In case of more such workbooks open in the same time, it will choose the first one of the array:

```
Sub takeTheMonthsNamedWB()
  Dim wbNames As Variant, wb As Workbook, w As Workbook, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
  wbNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July", ",") 'and so on...
  For Each w In Workbooks
    For Each El In wbNames
        If w.Name = "Docs_Tracker_" & El & " 2020.xlsm" Then
            Set wb = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If boolFound Then Exit For 'in order to stop iteration if a lot of workbooks are open
  Next
End Sub
```

Edited:

Try the next testing code, please. Does it return the correct workbook name?

```
Sub testTheMonthsNamedWB()
  Dim wbNames As Variant, w As Workbook, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
  wbNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July", ",") 'and so on...
    For Each El In wbNames
        Debug.Print "Docs_Tracker_" & El & " 2020.xlsm"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @CleanRider: Please use my test code (after editing). Does it return the workbook names as you need?

Answer (score 0):

> only two workbooks will be open ("control panel.xlsm" and "Docs
> tracker depending on the month"

If you would like to refer to the workbook which name depends on current month, you can use something like this:

```
Dim sWbkName As String, wbk As Workbook
sWbkName = "Docs_Tracker_" & Format(Date, "MMMM yyyy") & ".xlsm"
On Error Resume Next
Set wbk = Application.Workbooks(sWbkName)
If wbk Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't find '" & sWbkName & "'!!!" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Please, open it.", vbExclamation, "Error."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: it dosnt matter what the current month is , only the workbook we are working with. For example I am currently working on the April file howver it is now in October. (late entries get added depending on the month of revenue recognition)

Comment: OK. So, what the problem is with FaneDuru's code? Does it meet your criteria? If not, explain why...

Comment: His code is on the right path however I am having bugging issues. I have amended my code above to reflect changes he recommended. the line Set tbl = wb.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table_owssvr") requires debugging